# SPARQL - write a query to get uris refering to DBpedia ontology

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?pred WHERE {
  ?pred a rdf:Property
}
ORDER BY ?pred
```

which returns predicates like http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthYear and http://dbpedia.org/property/abandoned . How may I modify my query in order to get results with the prefix "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/" only?

Comment: `SELECT ?pred WHERE {
VALUES ?type {owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty}
  ?pred a ?type
} ORDER BY ?pred`

Comment: This query returns e. g. `http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P102s` today. It wasn't like this yesterday.

Comment: @StanislavKralin oh, ok. Didn't touch DBpedia for a while and didn't know that they loaded Wikidata schema. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AKSW provided one possible solution in comments, which may indeed get you what you want --

```
SELECT ?pred 
WHERE
 { VALUES ?type {owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty } 
   ?pred a ?type
 }
ORDER BY ?pred
```

That said, your question was specific in a way not answered by the above, so possibly *this* might be what you want --

```
SELECT ?pred 
WHERE
 { 
   ?pred a rdf:Property
   FILTER ( REGEX ( STR (?pred), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/", "i" ) )
 }
ORDER BY ?pred
```

Comment: I'd even go for [`strstarts`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts) function in case of namespace comparison - some triple stores might make use more efficient string checks with it (I know, probably none will do this). Regarding my suggestion, that will cover all mapping based properties, i.e. those with `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`

Comment: As of 2018-11-10, one could also try `SELECT DISTINCT ?pred
{
?pred a rdf:Property .
?pred rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
} ` or even `SELECT DISTINCT ?pred FROM <http://dbpedia.org/resource/classes#>
{
?pred a rdf:Property
} `

Comment: @StanislavKralin is there a new version now or why those changes? By the way, `DISTINCT` shouldn't be necessary for those queries. And the last query indeed returns all properties, so we would have to apply the namespace filter

Comment: @AKSW, the second query could be rather [this](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2Fclasses%23&qtxt=SELECT+count(DISTINCT+%3Fpred)+{+%3Fpred+a+rdf%3AProperty+}&format=text%2Fhtml)

Comment: @AKSW, and the first is rather [this](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+count%28%3Fpred%29+FROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2Fclasses%23%3E+%7B+%3Fpred+a+rdf%3AProperty+.+%3Fpred+rdfs%3AisDefinedBy+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E+%7D+&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) (compare results with and without `DISTINCT`).

Comment: @StanislavKralin I see, in the first query you have the union of the default graph `http://dbpedia.org` and the graph `http://dbpedia.org/resource/classes#` - that's why the duplicates occur. Clearly, this only holds for the Web UI - in a client the default graph isn't defined by default.

Comment: @AKSW, yes, probably `FROM NAMED` would be better.